# Is there a way to determine if a specific item is between two other specific items in a sequence?

Tags: logic

(I should preface by saying I have little experience with mathematical logic.)

Let's say I have the following logical statement:

$(\forall(x_n\in S)\notin\mathbb{N})\land(T)\Rightarrow\exists xP(x)$

wherein sequence S is finite and = (x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, $\ldots$ x<sub>n</sub>), and the values of x can only be the digits 0-9. This hopefully says that "for all items *x* in *S* that are zero and statement *T*, there exists at least one *P*.

I want statement *T* to more or less say "and x<sub>n</sub> is between two non-zero items in sequence *S* (any distance away from x<sub>n</sub>). This initially feels simple by saying: $T=((x_{n+1}\in S)\in\mathbb{N})\land((x_{n-1}\in S)\in\mathbb{N})$, but this has a few key problems. It only accounts for a distance of 1 from *n*, and thus would output $\bot$, or false, if either *x*<sub>n-1</sub> or *x*<sub>n+1</sub> were zero, even if they were "encircled" by nonzero items a distance of 2 away from *n*. For example, S = (3,0,0,0,3) would return false despite each zero being "encircled", and so would S = (6,0,0,7,8).

If at all possible, is there a way to say that, "if x<sub>n+1</sub>$\notin\mathbb{N}$,  go on to x<sub>n+2</sub>, x<sub>n+3</sub>,... until x<sub>n+whatever</sub>$\in\mathbb N$"? and similarly with x<sub>n-whatever</sub> . (Also I'd assume that if it never reached an item of zero, it was false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say if $x_{n+1} = 0$, go on to $x_{n+2}, \ldots$, to check for nonzero entries you can say:

$\exists m: n < m \leq k \wedge x_m \neq 0$

Where $k$ is the maximum index on $x$.